# Foreach condition issue

Tags: php, html, forms

I have the following code below but the problem is that it not working. The code is meant to update a quantity of whatever the users enters.

IF I echo `$type $size $quantity` i can see that the value as been sent.

`foreach ($_SESSION["cart_array"] as $array_key=>$each_item)` I think the problem is with this but I can't seem to see it.

***Can someone please take a look and see if they can find the problem please. Thanks***

**ISSUES**

if I enter a number in the form to update. It wouldn't update.

**PHP**

```
 <?php
   session_start();
    ?>
    <?php
if (isset($_POST['item_to_adjust']) && isset($_POST['size']) && isset($_POST['type'])) {
    $item_to_adjust = $_POST['item_to_adjust'];
    $type = $_POST['type'];
    $size = $_POST['size'];
    $quantity = $_POST['quantity'];
    $quantity = preg_replace('#[^0-9]#i', '', $quantity); // filter everything but numbers
    if ($quantity >= 100) { $quantity = 99; }
    if ($quantity < 1) { $quantity = 1; }
    if ($quantity == "") { $quantity = 1; }
    $i = 0;
    foreach ($_SESSION["cart_array"] as $array_key=>$each_item) { 
     $i++;
              if ($each_item['item_id'] == $item_to_adjust  && $each_item['size'] == $size && $each_item['type'] == $type) {
                      $_SESSION["cart_array"][$array_key]['quantity']+=$quantity;
                  } 
              } 
}
?>
```

**HTML**

```
<form action="cart.php" method="post">
        <input name="quantity" type="text" value="' . $each_item['quantity'] . '" size="1" maxlength="2" />
        <input name="adjustBtn' . $item_id . '" type="submit" value="Update" />
        <input name="size" type="hidden" value="' . $each_item['length'] . '" />
        <input name="type" type="hidden" value="' . $each_item['Category'] . '" />
        <input name="item_to_adjust" type="hidden" value="' . $item_id . '" />
        </form>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not sure but the problem you facing may be due to this:
try replacing this line

```
if ($each_item['item_id'] == $item_to_adjust  && $each_item['size'] == $size && $each_item['type'] == $type)
```

with this line:

```
if ($each_item['item_id'] == $item_to_adjust  && $each_item['length'] == $size && $each_item['Category'] == $type)
```

As in your session variable there is no key named "size" or "type" so basically when u check the condition $each_item['size'] == $size and $each_item['type'] == $type it is giving false(or in your case the Notice : Underfined Index:Type) in the If condition and hence not executing the If body which result in not updating the "quantity" value in the $_SESSION

As per ur comment do this: try replacing the line

```
$_SESSION["cart_array"][$array_key]['quantity']+=$quantity;
```

with:

```
$_SESSION["cart_array"][$array_key]['quantity'] = $quantity;
```

Comment: Thanks alot... wish i could give u 100 votes. I fixed that problem i need to remove the `+` from ** $_SESSION["cart_array"][$array_key]['quantity']+=$quantity; **